# View is returning FormCollection in Chrome but not IE

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0, razor

I have a View that has a DDL. Once a value is selected in the DDL the form can be submitted and the items for the vendor will be retrieved from a Web Api service and the page is reloaded. This form works as designed in Chrome but it fails to find the DDL value in the FormCollection object in IE. What did I miss?

View Code

```
@using AMCWeb.Models
@model AppointsViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}
<h2>Appraisal Appointment</h2>
@using (Html.BeginForm("GetAppointmentsByVendor", "AppraisalAppointment", FormMethod.Post, new {@id = "validationlist"}))
{
    <br/>
    <br/>

        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedCompany, new SelectList(Model.Vendors.OrderBy(s => s.Company), "Id", "Company", Model.SelectedCompany), "- Select Vendor -")
    <br/>
    <input type="submit" value="Get Appointments" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("GetAppointmentsByVendor", "AppraisalAppointment")'" />
    <br/>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Id</th>
            <th>Loan Number</th>
            <th>State</th>
            <th>Order Date</th>
            <th>Apt Date</th>
            <th>Est Due Date</th>
            <th>Fees</th>
            <th>MN Status</th>
        </tr>  

            @foreach (AMCWeb.Models.AppraisalAppointment appraisalAppointment in Model.Appraisals)
            {
                //...load the table with data
            }
    </table>
}
```

Controller Code

```
public ActionResult GetAppointmentsByVendor(FormCollection formValues)
{
   List<string> messages = new List<string>();
   if (formValues["selectedCompany"].Trim() == string.Empty)
   {
       messages.Add("You must select a Vendor to begin.");
       ViewBag.Messages = messages;
       appointments.Vendors = _vendorRepository.Get();
       return View("Index", appointments);
   }

   var vendorId = Convert.ToInt32(formValues["selectedCompany"]);
   appointments.Appraisals = _appraisalAppointmentRepository.GetByVendor(vendorId);
   appointments.Vendors = _vendorRepository.Get();
   appointments.SelectedCompany = vendorId;
   return View("Index", appointments);
}
```

Value from IE:
[image]

Value from Chrome:
[image]

UPDATE:
It appears that the vendorId was being passed. What I found was happening as I stepped through the code was it was indeed not in the FormCollection object, the code then broke on the first 'if statement' because it was not in the collection but if I continued to step through the code it jumped right back up the the first line `var vendorId = Convert.ToInt32(formValues["selectedCompany"]);` and the value was there. So I modified the code as follows

```
public ActionResult GetAppointmentsByVendor(FormCollection formValues)
{
    // to set up the model for reload
    IEnumerable<AppraisalAppointment> appointment = new[] { new AppraisalAppointment() };
    appointments.Appraisals = appointment;
    appointments.Vendors = _vendorRepository.Get();

    // for use in the tryparse
    var selectedCompany = formValues["selectedCompany"];
    int vendorId;

    // for message deliver to the user
    List<string> messages = new List<string>();

    // if the vendorId is not an int then they didn't select one return
    if (!Int32.TryParse(selectedCompany, out vendorId))
    {
        appointments.SelectedCompany = 0;
        messages.Add("You must select a Vendor to begin.");
        ViewBag.Messages = messages;
        return View("Index", appointments);
    }

    // get the data for the user
    appointments.Appraisals = _appraisalAppointmentRepository.GetByVendor(vendorId);
    appointments.SelectedCompany = vendorId;
    return View("Index", appointments);
}
```

Comment: interesting, if you look at the generated html do they both have the same form name?  my only guess is your html is invalid somewhere and IE doesn't like it.  Also do other form values work?

Comment: @Kyle, I check the html in IE tools and it looked fine and didn't complain about any errors.

Comment: It seems to be intermittent. I just ran it several times and this last time It finally sent the vendorId